# Завершить определённый поток последним

Tags: java, многопоточность

Поток 1: Происходит поиск новостей с выводом в конце `Search completed in..`.

```
Thread searchThread = new Thread(() -> readRSS());
searchThread.start();

public static void readRSS() {
    Window.Searching();
    for (i = 0; i < news_sources.length; i++) {
        /*много кода*/
    }
    //Search time
    Window.timeend = System.currentTimeMillis();
    searchTime = (Window.timeend - Window.timestart) / 1000;
    DecimalFormat f = new DecimalFormat("##.00");
    Window.lblSearch.setText("Search completed in "+f.format(searchTime)+" s.");
}
```

Поток 2: Параллельно с поиском сделана "анимация" поиска, путём добавления и убирания точек.

```
public static void Searching() {
    Thread thr = new Thread(() -> {
        for (News.i = 0; News.i < News.news_sources.length; ) {
            try {
                lblSearch.setText("Searching");
                Thread.sleep(500);
                lblSearch.setText("Searching.");
                Thread.sleep(500);
                lblSearch.setText("Searching..");
                Thread.sleep(500);
                lblSearch.setText("Searching.");
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    thr.start();
}
```

Всё работает красиво, но иногда после вывода, что поиск завершён, выскакивает поток с "анимацией" и вместо итога стоит "Searching.". Как сделать так, чтобы 2й поток никогда не продолжался после вывода итога первого потока?

Comment: вы в методе `Searching` не можете проверять, закончился ли первый поток или нет, перед тем, как писать что то в текстовое поле?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прямолинейный вариант: флаг завершения.

Создаем переменную, типа [`AtomicBoolean`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.html). Установим её в `false` при запуске поиска, и в `true` при завершении (до вывода результата). Передадим ее в `Searching`:

```
public static void readRSS() {
    AtomicBoolean isSearchFinished = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    Window.Searching(isSearchFinished);
    ...
    isSearchFinished.set(true);
    Window.lblSearch.setText("Search completed in " + f.format(searchTime) + " s.");
}
```

В потоке анимации проверяем флаг и, если поиск завершен, то ничего не делаем:

```
public static void Searching(AtomicBoolean isSearchFinished) {
    ...
    if(isSearchFinished.get()) return;
    lblSearch.setText("Searching");
    Thread.sleep(500);
    if(isSearchFinished.get()) return;
    lblSearch.setText("Searching.");
}
```

Не проверял, но вроде должно сработать.

Еще варианты:

- Возвращать из `Searching` ссылку на поток анимации. Перед выводом результатов прерывать поток (`interrupt`) и дожидаться завершения (`join`).
- Создать переменную-флаг на уровне класса и синхронизировать к ней доступ.

Comment: Благодарю, добрый человек!